# Flask template not finding list items as expected

Tags: python, flask, debugging

I am working on a multiuser pixel art system similar to r/place on Reddit. However, I cannot figure out how to solve this bug I ran into. What's happening is that for some reason, it is not detecting the pixel in the list even though it's clearly there. I checked repl db to see if there are any keys and also checked the database list where database items are saved to see if it is there. They are there. I think it's because once it moves on, it will not go back to the previous item, so it causes it to not detect the pixel. I'm planning to use a fix where it just grabs it from the list when it's detected on the list, but I do not know how to do this or how to get it to accurately detect the pixel, especially since the items on the list are in JSON form.
Here is my server code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from replit import db
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True #if true, it auto reloads templates if a change is made to them
app.secret_key = os.environ['SECRET_KEY'] #The secret key
board_size = 60 #The size of the pixel board (Warning: A very large size may either break the app or overload repl db)
database = [] #Stores data from the database for faster loading speeds and optimization
for i in db.keys(): #loops through all keys in the database
     database.append(db[i])
"""Routes"""
@app.route('/')
def index():
    """The index page (Board is on it)"""
    keys = db.keys()
    return render_template('index.html', size=board_size, db=database, keys=keys)
"""Socketio events"""
@socketio.on('pixel_change')
def change_pixel(pixel):
  db[pixel['Pixel']] = pixel
  print( db[pixel['Pixel']])
  print(db.keys())
  database.append(pixel)
  emit('change_pixel', {'Pixel': pixel['Pixel'], 'Color': pixel['Color']}, broadcast=True)
socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Pixel Board</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='board' class='board'>
    {% for i in range(0, size) %}
<div class='row'>
      {% for j in range(0, size) %}
        <div class='pixel' id='pixel_{{i}}_{{j}}' {%if db[j] and db[j].Pixel == "pixel_{{i}}_{{j}}" %} style='background-color: {{db[j].Color}} {%else%} style='background-color:red '{%endif%} onclick='select({{i}}, {{j}})'></div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
  </div>
  <button id='submit_btn' disabled>Place Pixel</button>
  <script src='static/js/script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is someone able to help?
I also set the pixels to turn red if it's not detected for debugging purposes. I am also sorry if my question is confusing to some people.